# efficient way to calculate all possible multiplication elements inside a vector in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Is there any efficient way of doing the following:
Assume I have a vector `A` of length n, I want to calculate a second vector `B`, where

```
B[i] = A[0] * A[1] * .. *A[i-1] * A[i+1] *..*A[n-1]
```

i.e., B[i] is the multipication of all elements in A except for the i'th elmenet.
Initially, I thought of doing something like:

```
C = np.prod(A)
B = C/A
```

But, then I have a problem when I have an element of A which is equal to zero. Of course, I can
find out if I have one zero and then immediately set B to be the all-zero vector except for that
single zero and to put there the multiple of the rest of A and in the case of more than 1 zero to zero out B completely. But this becomes a little cumbersome when I want to do that operation for every row inside a matrix and not just for a single vector.
Of course, I can do it in a loop but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You could slice up to (but not including) `i`, then from `i+1` and on. Concatenate those slices together and multiply.

```
np.prod(np.concatenate([a[:i], a[i+1:]]))
```

Comment: But then I'll have to loop over i...which is not efficient

Answer (score 0):

A possible one liner using `np.eye`, `np.tile` and `np.prod`:

```py
np.prod(np.tile(A, (A.size, 1))[(1 - np.eye(A.size)).astype(bool)].reshape(A.size, -1), axis=1)
```